# css/jquery: Fixed when scrolling horizontally but not vertically

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a large table with headers as the first column, and a jQuery slider plugin (from https://github.com/keesschepers/jquery-ui-content-slider) to scroll through the table horizontally while keeping the first column fixed.

However, if I try to scroll downwards (vertically) I cannot see the rest of first column (larger than the height of the screen) since it has the fixed property (css). Is there any css or jQuery trick to fix this?

CSS Code:

```
     table tr td:first-child { position: fixed; }
```

HTML Code:

```
      <div id="#content-scroll">
      <table>
      <tr><td></td>...and many more cells</tr>
      ...and many more rows
      </table></div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
             <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#content-slider").slider({
                animate: true,
                change : function (e, ui) {
                    var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").prop("scrollWidth") -
                        $("#content-scroll").width();
                    $("#content-scroll").animate({
                        scrollLeft : ui.value * (maxScroll / 100)
                    }, 1000);
                },
                slide : function (e, ui)
                {
                    var maxScroll = $("#content-scroll").prop("scrollWidth") -
                        $("#content-scroll").width();
                    $("#content-scroll").prop('scrollLeft' ,ui.value * (maxScroll / 100));
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you try setting a height and overflow-y on the tbody?

Comment: Change `overflow:hidden` on #content-scroll to `overflow-x: hidden;` if you want inline vertical scrolling, else set the height to a heigher value or check it with jquery :)

Comment: @fudgey I don't have a tbody anywhere in my code, and I'm not sure how having one would help..

Comment: @Marco Johannesen overflow-x only stops table overflow horizontally, and overflow-y vertically. Neither allow scrolling down the fixed first column. I can scroll down the rest of the table except the first column.

Comment: table tr td:first-child {
 position:absolute;
 left:8px; }
seems to work, but disturbs the normal flow of the table...

Comment: Most modern browsers will automatically add a tbody to a table, but it is good practice to add one anyway. What might be an even better idea would be to replace the `td` with a `th` in the column you want fixed.

Comment: @fudgey ok thanks will keep that in mind~ I did actually replace the td with th, and I did try the tbody method but it didn't work.. :( as I mentioned above overflow-y doesn't help a fixed column. Absolute column seems to be causing problems as well since it's really setting the absolute position for the first cell of each row...

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I'm not too familiar with that table library, so I just threw something together here that works on FireFox (I'm sure Kees Schepers handles the cross-browser styling better than I care to).

Anyway, the important part is the div (`#d`) around the table (`#t`) with `position:relative;`. That allows the `position:absolute;` of the `:first-child` elements to take effect relative to the stationary `#d` instead of the scrolling `#t`.

Sample HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #d { /*** Important part is here ***/
        position:relative;
    }
    #t {
        display:block;
        overflow-x:scroll;
        overflow-y:visible;
        width:412px;
    }
    #t tbody {
        display:block;
        margin-left:202px;
    }
    #t th,
    #t td {
        border:1px solid #000;
    }
    #t tr th:first-child,
    #t tr td:first-child {
        background:#FFF;
        left:0;
        position:absolute;
        width:200px;
    }
    #t tr td div {
        height:200px;
        width:200px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="d">
        <table id="t" cell-padding="0" cell-spacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>head1</th>
                <th>head2</th>
                <th>head3</th>
                <th>head4</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div>###</div></td>
                <td><div>###</div></td>
                <td><div>###</div></td>
                <td><div>###</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div>###</div></td>
                <td><div>###</div></td>
                <td><div>###</div></td>
                <td><div>###</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps some.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has kindly written this for you to do exactly what you need, as a solution for making tables work in a responsive layout. Check it out:

http://www.zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables

Comment: It works perfectly on Firefox, unfortunately not at all on IE :/